# VB.NET: Why doesn't this nullable work?

Tags: vb.net

```
dim str as nullable(of string)
```

is this syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nullable(Of T)` is only applicable to non-nullable value types. String is a class - a reference type. A variable of type `String` can already have a null value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Dim x As String = Nothing` sets `x` to `Nothing` (not `""`).

Comment: @Dan: Thanks, removed that bit. Maybe it's just *comparisons* with Nothing which are strange in VB. (If you set `x` to "" and then print `x = Nothing` it will print True.)

Comment: @Jon: Wow, that is bizarre... I guess I assumed VB.NET's `=` operator would use the `System.String` type's `op_Equality` method. Maybe it does, but there's some weird conversion from `Nothing` to `""` going on?

Comment: @Dan - string comparison in VB.NET requires a helper function because of Option Compare.  That helper function treats Nothing as an empty string.  Backward compat is tough.

Comment: Integer is a non-nullable value type that can be made nullable by As Nullable(Of Integer), so is Integer a non-nullable value type?  There is humor here.